# Using external library with angular cli

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have installed one 3rd party module [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) with my angular app. The module works perfectly but I get an error in my console:

`Cannot find module '../../../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js'`.

**What I did:**

1. Install the module via npm:

`npm install MrRio/jsPDF --save`

2. Import the module in my component:

`import * as jsPDF from '../../../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js';`

3. Then simply works with this module in my component.

Is something missing here?

Comment: Have a look at the instructions here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation. If jsPDF needs to be in the global scope, you will need to add the JS file to `apps[0].scripts` in your `angular-cli.json` file, which WebPack then bundles as if it were loaded with a `<script>` tag. If you do the latter, you can get at it by adding `declare var jsPDF: any;` in your `src/typings.d.ts` or component. However, it looks like there are typings for jsPDF https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jspdf so you can include it; but you should be able to `import { jsPDF} from 'jspdf';`

Comment: @Harry Thank you. You could post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked, thank you, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the instructions here: [github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installatio‌​n](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib).

If jsPDF (or any other library) needs to be in the global scope, you will need to add the JS file to `apps[0].scripts` in your `angular-cli.json` file, which WebPack then bundles as if it were loaded with a `<script>` tag. If you do that, you can get at it by adding `declare var jsPDF: any;` in your `src/typings.d.ts` or component.

However, it looks like there are typings for jsPDF [npmjs.com/package/@types/jspdf](http://npmjs.com/package/@types/jspdf) so you can include it after running `npm install --save-dev @types/jspdf`; you should be able to `import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';` in your component.