# Implement plugin angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a little problem with Angular 4 : 
how can I implement plugins as node-module ? ( like https://datatables.net/ or https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/ )

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read how to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can map it up in the systemjs.config else if you are using ng-cli start using it directly after installing https://medium.com/@kermani/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526476/using-external-library-with-angular-cli

Comment: I've been using this: https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library and it's great ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try these modules just follow the instructions.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-chartist
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-4-data-table