# How to include an external JS library into an Angular CLI project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to include [this library] `http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/` into my angular-cli project. How can I do that?

I tried like this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526476/using-external-library-with-angular-cli`
and like this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526476/using-external-library-with-angular-cli`
This solutions not work for me. I'm still getting in the console
'picturefill is not defined`.

Comment: very helpfull guys :/

Answer (score -1):

I think making one simple google search would have given you the answer:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Comment: You think that I don't know about google?))I try like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120754/using-external-js-libraries-in-my-angular-2-project
and like this https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af 
and some more links, but js file still not working

Comment: well, your question wasn't very elaborate to begin with. And now you just keep saying that it doesn't work. It works for all of us so you can start by saying how you diverged from a standard project. maybe the library is incompatible?

Comment: Sorry for my question. The library is only available if I add it by inserting a <script> tag into index.html. But I think this is not the most correct way.